# Excel VBA coping and pasting numerous shapes now erroring in Windows 10 but did not in 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit of a novice at VBA but have always found solutions from reading forums.

I now have an issue that I can't resolve, my company recently switched from Windows 2016 to Windows 10 (luckily at the moment I still have both laptops) but I am having issues with my code inconsistently erroring in a few Excel VBA tools I had developed in the old version.

My colleague also had this issue but managed to resolve his issue by disabling and enabling missing libraries.. I have tried this but not resolving.

The error..

Basically my tool "draws" a Gantt view of projects by copying and pasting shapes, resizing them and renaming them in specified cell locations.. previous version no issues at all took a few seconds.. Windows 10 is being completely inconsistent.. sometimes it will run with no issues (say 20% of the time) and then it will error at completely different areas of the code!

The error I get is "Run-time Error 1004 Paste method of Worksheet class failed"

I'm not sure why my code would run find in old Windows but not Windows 10.. but it maybe because my code is a bit rubbish and selecting the shapes and cells etc and it just can't cope sometimes?

Here is an example of the code I'm using, any advice would be appreciated:

```
Sub DrawDevelopment()

Dim rngData As Range

Set rngData = Sheets("Gantt Extract").Range("a4:a300")

    For Each G In rngData


        G_Address = G.Offset(0, 39).Value
        G_size = G.Offset(0, 40).Value
        G_Scheme = G.Offset(0, 1).Value

        If G_Address <> "" Then

            Sheets("Gantt").Shapes("Development").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range(G_Address).Select
            Sheets("Gantt").Paste
            Selection.Name = "Delete" & (G_Scheme)
            With Selection.ShapeRange
                .Width = G_size
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 4
    
            Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoBringToFront
                
           End With
        End If

    Next G
    

End Sub
```

[Example of what overall code is drawing with shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Q1m.png)

Answer (score 1):

While not specific to Windows 10, something might be causing an issue that is being exposed by the use of unqualified `Select` statements here.

I've tried re-writing it without the `Select` - but in order to test it I had to strip away the `ShapeRange` usage also before it would work with *my* shapes.

There might be a better way to reference the pasted shape, but I couldn't see one immediately so this does look a bit messy but works on my Win10 machine:

```
Sub DrawDevelopment()

    Dim rngData As Range
    
    Dim shtCopyFrom As Worksheet
    Dim shtCopyTo As Worksheet
    
    Set shtCopyFrom = Sheets("Gantt")
    Set shtCopyTo = Sheets("Gantt Extract")
    Set rngData = shtCopyTo.Range("a4:a300")
        
    For Each g In rngData.Cells
        G_Address = g.Offset(0, 39).Value
        G_size = g.Offset(0, 40).Value
        G_Scheme = g.Offset(0, 1).Value
        If G_Address <> "" Then
            shtCopyFrom.Shapes("Development").Copy
            With shtCopyTo
                .Paste
                Set objShape = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                objShape.Name = "Delete" & (G_Scheme)
                Set pasteCell = .Range(G_Address)
                With objShape
                    .Width = G_size
                    .IncrementTop 4
                    .ZOrder msoBringToFront
                    .Left = pasteCell.Left
                    .Top = pasteCell.Top
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next g
End Sub
```